# gcc equivalent of -Wshorten-64-to-32

Tags: gcc, clang

clang has a flag -Wshorten-64-to-32 which is useful in detecting illegal narrowings. gcc doesn't support this as of 5.4.0; is there an equivalent flag?

Answer (score -3):

Clang `-Wnarrowing` checks for this and other narrrowing issues.

Comment: That's not what this question seems to ask not sure why you put it as answer.